# Jquery Add To List from text boxs

Tags: jquery

I have got the following list

```
<ul id="js-news" class="js-hidden">
    <li class="news-item"><a href="#">This is the 1st latest news item.</a></li>
    <li class="news-item"><a href="#">This is the 2nd latest news item.</a></li>
    <li class="news-item"><a href="#">This is the 3rd latest news item.</a></li>
    <li class="news-item"><a href="#">This is the 4th latest news item.</a></li>
</ul>
```

This runs via a news ticker that i found on-line How would i go about adding to the list using jquery from a text box with a add button.

Is it possible to add to this list from a a different page using jquery.

Comment: How do you mean 'Is it possible to add to this list from a a different page using jquery'? Is the ticker running in an frame? If you're on another page, how can the ticker be visible?

Comment: sure, just use [append](http://jsfiddle.net/22Jx2/).

Comment: I have the news ticker on the homepage and i have the list on the same page. If i was to create a admin section on a different page that would allow the user to be able to update the news ticker

Comment: You would need to use a database and server-side code. jQuery would not be the solution in that scenario.

Comment: How would i allow the user to add code from a text box using append

Answer (score 2):

To add extra items to your list, try this code:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    var $li = $("<li></li>").addClass("news-item");
    var $a = $("<a></a>").attr("href", "#").text("This is the Nth item").appendTo($li);
    $li.appendTo("#js-news");
});
```

Note that you may need to re-initialise your news ticker component, depending on whether it reads the `li` element into an array on load, or is constantly referencing them to pick up additiions.

Comment: so much nicer than my primitive answer :)

Comment: Do i not need to have some form of click event so that when i click a button it adds from the text box>

Comment: @Inkey Unless you wanted it to add an item on page load you would - I've edited the code so it's inside a click handler.

Comment: Cheers my code now looks now 
  $(function () {
        $('#js-news').ticker();
        $("#myButton").click(function () {
            var $li = $("<li></li>").addClass("news-item");
            var $a = $("<a></a>").attr("href", "#").text("This is the Nth item").appendTo($li);
            $li.appendTo("#js-news");
        });
    });
then i have my list and my button and noting happens when i press the button

Comment: install firebug so that you can see if there's any javascript error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only if is pop up window, and that needs to be opened by you site.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want a news ticker, you also want other people can see it i think? :).
So you need to create a new form in php or any other language you are using for the website and add a new news item in a database.
On the page where you want to display this, just read the values from the database and create a list of them.

greets,
stefan.